# Cannot read BITMAPFILEHEADER of a bitmap file using C++

Tags: c++, bitmap

I am trying to read the FILEHEADER and INFOHEADER of a bitmap file, but I am unable to do so. I am getting `Segmentation Fault`.

My code has been given below.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

typedef int LONG;
typedef unsigned short WORD;
typedef unsigned int DWORD;

struct BITMAPFILEHEADER {
  WORD  bfType;
  DWORD bfSize;
  WORD  bfReserved1;
  WORD  bfReserved2;
  DWORD bfOffBits;
};

struct BITMAPINFOHEADER {
  DWORD biSize;
  LONG  biWidth;
  LONG  biHeight;
  WORD  biPlanes;
  WORD  biBitCount;
  DWORD biCompression;
  DWORD biSizeImage;
  LONG  biXPelsPerMeter;
  LONG  biYPelsPerMeter;
  DWORD biClrUsed;
  DWORD biClrImportant;
};

int main(void){
    ifstream file("lena.bmp");
    char* bf = NULL;
    int begin = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, ios::end);
    int end = file.tellg();
    int length = end-begin;

    file.read(bf, length);
    BITMAPFILEHEADER* file_header = (BITMAPFILEHEADER*)(bf);
    //BITMAPINFOHEADER* info_header = (BITMAPINFOHEADER*)(bf+sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)-1);

    cout << file_header->bfSize << endl;
    //cout << info_header->biSize << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That include file appearing in your code looks really really sketchy.

Comment: this includes all the c and c++ header files. i am quite sure that is not the problem.

Comment: I don't think it is, but it makes the code completely non-portable across compilers, and as I doubt the header is documented, being in the bits folder, the behaviour of the header is probably free to change in any future update.

Comment: okay, i will look into it. thanks. but that is not the problem right now. i am getting segmentation error. and i can't figure out my error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The segmentation fault is probably because you forgot to initialize `bf`;

```
int end = file.tellg();
int length = end-begin;
bf = new char[lenght+1]; //Add this
file.seekg(0, ios::beg); //And this too
file.read(bf, length);
```

[EDIT]

The second problem (size is always 0) occurs because the file pointer is at the end of the file, so you never read anything actually.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was very kind of you. It has removed my error. But can you please help me with another issue. I am getting size  = 0 everytime. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, I notice the same thing... I'm not familiar with this structure, let me see.

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in the previous reply, you where trying to `file.read` with a null pointer.
I see that you are trying to load the whole file into memory, then do some pointer arithmetics to work with the data. But why not just read the `BITMAPFILEHEADER` directly instead?

```
ifstream file("lena.bmp");

// read in the header:
BITMAPFILEHEADER header;
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&header), sizeof(header));

// validate the header, get the size in bytes of the bitmap data
size_t bitmapSizeBytes = width * height * channels; // or something like that...

// Now read the bitmap. Use a vector to simplify memory management:
std::vector<unsigned char> bitmap;
bitmap.resize(bitmapSizeBytes);

file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&bitmap[0]), bitmapSizeBytes);
```

Comment: I am sorry but from where are these variables coming from, width * height * channels. If i sound stupid then I am sorry but i am new to all of these.

Comment: No, for the contrary, I apologise. I've made those vars up because I don't quite remember the structure of a Windows .bmp file. This is just a pseudo-code to guide you. Images are usually laid out like this, a width times a height times the number of color channels. But the point I wanted to make was that you should just read the header directly and use a vector for the image data, instead of a raw char* pointer.